# Timer more reliable than System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I'm currently using the System.Threading.Timer on a 10 second interval. I've adding a small piece of code to write to a file each time the timer fires, and whilst most of the time it fires on-time, sometimes (presumably when the rest of the app is buy), fails to fire for 30 or 40 seconds, and fires over and over again in quick succession.

Is there a more reliable timer I can use in .NET 3.5?

The timer is setup as follows

```
Timer someTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(SomeMethod), null, 0, 10000);
```

...and the callback is:

```
private static void SomeMethod(object state)
```

However, it's difficult to provide much more code than this, as the Timer usually fires correctly. When it's embedded in a massive application (~100,000 lines or so), with mulitple threads being fired off, left, right, and centre, you slowly start to see the timer firing intermitently.
I've seen several posts suggesting the ThreadPool may be exhausted, so I'm currently looking in to see if this might be what I'm experiencing.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code instead of *assuming* the timer is unreliable? I tend to find it's my own code that is the problem and not the .NET Frameworks'.

Comment: The timer is set-up as follows:

Comment: ThreadPool starvation will very probably be the case if the processing the tick does takes long than 10 seconds. You will slowly get a backlog of items. The standard tactic is to stop the timer on entry to a tick event and start it again at the end to not have "timer leak" due to long processing times.

Comment: Are you using by any chance a `Parallel.ForEach` or `Parallel.For` loop anywhere in your application? If you do, make sure to configure the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to a reasonable value (like `Environment.ProcessorCount`). Otherwise you'll get the effects of unlimited parallelism (the default configuration), which means that the `ThreadPool` will be saturated until the source enumerable completes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds exactly like thread pool starvation. Look out for long running/blocking jobs running in the thread pool and either rewrite using async io, or in the case of long running CPU intensive jobs, simply don't run these jobs in the thread pool. Run them on their own thread or use a background worker.

Comment: I was hoping it might just have been a problems specific to System.Threading.Timer, and that by switching to another Timer, I'd be able to get around the problem. After your hints and with some closer inspection, it does indeed look like a ThreadPool starvation problem. Thanks for all the help, people.

Answer (score 8):

Refer different timer classes in .net

[image: Different Timer class in .net]

There are three timer classes called 'Timer' in .NET. It sounds like you're using the Windows Forms one, but actually you might find the System.Threading.Timer class more useful - but be careful because it calls back on a pool thread, so you can't directly interact with your form from the callback.

**More Accurate Timer - As per MSDN**

The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds. If you require a multithreaded timer with greater accuracy, use the Timer class in the System.Timers namespace.

Comment: Sounds like he is using it perhaps, but he actually states he is using `System.Threading.Timer`, which according to the metronome quality is one of the two most "reliable" to pick.

Comment: Hi Romil, thanks for that, as others have pointed out, it seems to be a ThreadPool starvation issue, but thanks for the table nonetheless. I'm sure it will come in handy sooner or later.

Comment: Actually the [`System.Timers Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer) is not thread safe: *"Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."*, and the [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) is: *"This type is thread safe."*